# Need to filter dates by month in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, filter

Have data on temperature that spans multiple years in 2010-01-01 format. I want to isolate the temps from June and am unsure how to filter this. Typically the method I use would be 
`df[df['date'] == 2016]` but this only parses out by year.

Comment: What do you mean by _isolate the temps from June_ ? Can you share your code? See: [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method `dt.month_name()`

```
df[df['date'].dt.month_name() == 'June']
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use a datetime method ontop of your datetime to access the month

```
impot pandas as pd
rng = pd.date_range('2010-01-01','2011-01-01',freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':rng})
```

#### Print Head of DataFrame.

```
print(df.head(5))
     dates
0 2010-01-01
1 2010-01-02
2 2010-01-03
3 2010-01-04
4 2010-01-05
```

#### use a `.loc` accessor to filter the dataframe with a dt.month method:

```
df.loc[df['dates'].dt.month == 2]
     dates
31 2010-02-01
32 2010-02-02
33 2010-02-03
34 2010-02-04
35 2010-02-05
36 2010-02-06
```

Ensure your date is a proper datetime object by using `pd.to_datetime`

use `print(df.dtypes)` to check the datatypes.